# trying to update my MongoDB collection via Python (PyMongo) but my logic is wrong

Tags: python, mongodb, for-loop, if-statement, pymongo

I'm new to programming and I've been learning Flask for about a week now, trying to design an e-commerce website.

I have a collection called `users`, in which each entry looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9170f1c5eb754e3ab8917f"),
    "username" : "suhas",
    "password" : "suhas",
    "email" : "suhas",
    "account_type" : "buyer",
    "cart" : [
        {
            "product_id" : "5b915dd3c5eb754278e160e7",
            "quantity" : 7
        },
        {
            "product_id" : "5b915e3fc5eb754278e160e8",
            "quantity" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

and a `users.products` collection, one of the elements look like this

{

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b915f02c5eb7544108a14b9"),
    "product name" : "Laptop",
    "price" : 50000,
    "description" : "HP laptop",
    "user_id" : "5b914fc3c5eb753eaf81770c",
    "username" : "chiranth"
}
```

I wanted to add a feaure "add to cart" that adds the product_id and quantity into a cart(type list) as dictionaries, as seen in the db.users collection.

The code in Python I've written as:

```
cart_dict = user_info.get("cart")    


    for dict1 in cart_dict:
        if dict1["product_id"]==product_id:
            db["users"].update({"_id" : ObjectId(user_id),"cart.product_id":product_id},{ '$inc':{ 'cart.$.quantity':quantity}})
            break
        else:
            db["users"].update({"_id":ObjectId(user_id)},{"$addToSet":{"cart":{"$each":[{"product_id":product_id,"quantity":quantity}]}}})
```

The problem is, however, that if I increment the second product by adding 2 more to the cart adding to the present 3, the `if` condition checks the first product, sees that product ID doesn't match and just adds it as a new product AND THEN moves to product 2.

So my question would be: how do I ask the `if` condition to check all product_id's first AND THEN, if none match, add the product?

EDIT : to clarify,
my issue is with the IF condition. I want it to first compare product A, if that isnt satisfied, move to product B, and IF neither  match, THEN it should go to the else loop. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey the code you have provided, their is **unnecessary second for loop** on same data just above the `if` condition.

you should remove that line.  As pr updating data the code i used and works is as :

```
collection.update({'_id':int(n)},{'$set' : {'CloseDate':TodayDate,'Status':'close'}})
```

in this the where is provided in `_id` and the fields `CloseDate` & `Status` are being updated, this works, so you should put your new values that are to be updated in DB in some variables and directly assign them in your documents name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oops. Thanks about the double 'for'. As for the code, my issue is with the IF statement. lets i have 2 products A and B. i want to add more of B to the cart.

Comment: okay, then apply a condition for checking in ID of that product in loop and if it gives true, update it.

Comment: Welcome happy to help, kindly upvote and accept the solution.